# Indexing object for using in ARRAY_CONTAINS in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose I've the following data in my container:

```
{
    "id": "1DBF704E-1623-4844-DC86-EFA729A5C048",
    "firstName": "Wylie",
    "lastName": "Ramsey",
    "state": "AZ",
    "country": "United State",
    "cards": [
        {
            "creditCardNumType": "visa-electron",
            "creditCardNum": "4405306101455297"
        },
        {
            "creditCardNumType": "diners-club-enroute",
            "creditCardNum": "201448447389873"
        },
        {
            "creditCardNumType": "visa-electron",
            "creditCardNum": "3549404485000802"
        }       
    ]
}
```

And I use the following query to get all the people who have specific card type:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.cards, {'creditCardNumType': 'visa-electron'}, true)
```

What is the correct way to index the field 'c.cards' (I don't want the default indexing)? Should it be `/cards/*` or `/cards/creditCardNumType/?`?

Answer (score 0):

I think neither `/cards/*` or `/cards/creditCardNumType/?`can help you. Because `cards` is an array type, it's index should be `/cards/[]/*`(It would index anything under `cards`). If you only want to index `creditCardNumType` property，it should be `/cards/[]/creditCardNumType/?`.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#include-exclude-paths

[Azure Cosmos DB Add Composite Index for Array of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583569/azure-cosmos-db-add-composite-index-for-array-of-string)